# Override appearanceWhenContainedIn on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have some general styles which are being setup when my application loads:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[NRWindow class], nil] setTintColor:kBlueColor];
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[NRWindow class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kFontNameLatoRegular size:14]];
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[NRWindow class], nil] setFontName:kFontNameLatoRegular];
```

For some reason, it affects the placeholder font size. 
On a specific view, I want to override those styles (just for the placeholder) using the following code:

```
 UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFontNameLatoLight size:16];
 self.emailTextField.font = font;
 self.emailTextField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Email Address" attributes: @{ NSFontAttributeName:font}];
```

For some reason, the placeholder is not getting the right font.
However, if I comment the general styles (appearanceWhenContainedIn) it works perfect. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Solution

Note: Keep in mind that this fix has only been tested on iOS 6.0 and up.

To work around this bug, you have to create a subclass of UITextField and override the -setAttributedPlaceHolder to store the result in an ivar. Then you have to override the -drawPlaceholderInRect method and enumerate over the attributes and draw the text using -drawAtPoint method of NSAttributedString+NSStringDrawing (the only iOS 6 specific method). This allow support for custom attributes which can help when tweeking a design.

http://engineering.meetme.com/2013/11/uitextfield-attributedplaceholder-doesnt-work/

Comment: That is clever but I don't see why you didn't solve it by using another `appearanceWhenContainedIn` aimed at your UITextField subclass. That is the usual approach: first set appearance in general, then set appearance in particular to override.

Answer (score -2):

***OUTDATED ANSWER, please don't do this, we have other options***

Use a recursive function to get the UITextField then set the props

```
extension UIView {

func recursive_applyTheme_Search(
    #dynamicTextStyle: NSString,
    bgColor: UIColor,
    cursorColor: UIColor,
    textColor: UIColor,
    placeholderTextColor: UIColor,
    borderColor: UIColor,
    borderWidth: CGFloat,
    cornerRadius: CGFloat) {

    for subview in self.subviews
    {
        if subview is UITextField {

            (subview as! UITextField).applyThemeForSearchBar(
                dynamicTextStyle: dynamicTextStyle,
                bgColor: bgColor,
                cursorColor: cursorColor,
                textColor: textColor,
                placeholderTextColor: placeholderTextColor,
                borderColor: borderColor,
                borderWidth: borderWidth,
                cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        }
        else { subview.recursive_applyTheme_Search(
                dynamicTextStyle: dynamicTextStyle,
                bgColor: bgColor,
                cursorColor: cursorColor,
                textColor: textColor,
                placeholderTextColor: placeholderTextColor,
                borderColor: borderColor,
                borderWidth: borderWidth,
                cornerRadius: cornerRadius) }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: totally unecessary

Comment: Yes, agree, but in 2015 at that moment we tried like everything and only this worked